# Word or phrase that refers to whom I report to and who reports to me

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm working on an application that allows a user to search through a directory of employees and display them within an org chart.

One way to view an employee is within the context of their whole department. For now, I'm referring to this as the "department chart".

Since some employees report to someone *outside* of their department, the other way to view an employee is with their immediate supervisor and their immediate subordinates only, regardless of department. I cannot for the life of me figure out what to call this view. I need a word or very short phrase that would describe where an employee sits between their supervisor and subordinates without getting confused with the view of the department hierarchy.

Thanks!

Comment: Hierarchy chart?

Comment: @WS2 - that was one I thought of but would that be easily confused with the department hierarchy?

Comment: **Organisational structures**? Here's [a list of 8 types](http://www.yourarticlelibrary.com/organization/8-types-of-organisational-structures-their-advantages-and-disadvantages/22143/). If you could give an example, I could tell you what kind of structure it is.

Comment: @NVZ - Looking.

Comment: @NVZ - It probably best fits either the Line or Divisional organizational structures.

Comment: I recommend that you look up "organisational structures" on Google. If you can find the right answer, you may post it yourself. It's [highly encouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/309993). I say this because I cannot suggest a particular structure without more details in the question.

Comment: I don't think any of those 8 types describe what I'm asking for, though, to be honest. I'm not necessarily looking for a word to describe the type of hierarchy the company fits into, I'm more looking for something that describes the limit of immediate supervisors and subordinates instead of a full department.

Comment: "Reporting lines", "Org chart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with **Chain of Command**.

> **chain of command:**  a series of executive positions in order of authority
>
> <sub>From [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chain%20of%20command)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

What about **Dependency Chart**

> [dependency](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dependency): something dependent or subordinate

Comment: That's not bad.

Comment: When I see the word "dependency", I don't know if I immediately think of the manager/employee relationship though. But not bad...

Comment: I imagine both directions, i think it is about getting used to

Comment: Perhaps. I'll probably leave the question open for a while but I'll accept your answer if nobody posts anything better. Thank you!

Comment: @TheIronCheek it's better to wait at least 2 days before accepting one. Because once it's accepted, nobody will bother answering this.

Comment: That's what I meant by a while. ;)